# How to use something like the charAt for integers

Tags: java, string, char, int, charat

I am trying to make a program that uses three digit numbers to identify items and I am trying to use something like the charAt method for integers or something. Im not too sure. Im a beginner and I apologize i just need help. Also I need a bit of help to use an if statement and relational operators. Im trying to do if the last digit in the number is less than 5 then it is {item} and if its greater than 5 then its this {item}. Something like that. Thank you so much in advance.

```
    String number;

    System.out.println("Enter three digit number: ");
    number = in.nextLine();

    switch (number.charAt(0))
    {
         //stuff
    }

    if (number > 5)
    {
      //it is this item
    {
    else
    {
      //it is the other item
    {
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways you can do it:

1. ```
   String number = in.nextLine();
   char c = number.charAt(i); // i is the position of digit you want to retrieve
   int digit = c - '0';
   ```
2. if you want to get ith digit from the end of an Integer, do:

   ```
   int digit = 0;
   while(i > 0) {
       digit = n%10;
       n /= 10;
       --i;
   }
   ```

Comment: Okay say you enter 303. I want the if to take the last number and determine what it would do based if its greater than five or not.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    String number;
    System.out.println("Enter three digit number: ");
    number = in.nextLine(); //this is 305
    if (number.charAt(2) > 5) //My issue is number is a string and > doesn't                        work with strings
    {
      //it is this item
    {

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Integer num = Integer.parseInt(number);

Answer (score 1):

To check the last digit of a base-10 number, use the remainder operator:

```
if (number % 10 < 5) {
    // handle last digit is 0-4
} else {
    // handle last digit is 5-9
}
```

Comment: But my problem is number is a string

Comment: Then use `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()`.