# How to make charAt() return a number you can fill in an array?

Tags: java

I got a task where the user writes in a string, and the a constructor will use `charAt()` and `length()` to fill in in an array how many times each letter occur.

My problem is that I don't know how to make the `charAt()` method return a value I can fill into the array.

Here is what I have so far. I'm really new to coding.

```java
public class TekstVerktøy{
    private String text;
    private int[] letterArray = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    /* Konstruktør */
    public TekstVerktøy(String t){
        int i = 0;
        letterArray = letterArray;
        this.text = t;

        while(i <= this.text.length()){
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply add your character to the `int` array it will be implicitly casted to it's `int` value.

Comment: What you want to achieve ?? tell your expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use something like the charAt for integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854399/how-to-use-something-like-the-charat-for-integers)

Comment: `letterArray = letterArray;` why?

Comment: Don't I have to get the letterArray inside the constructor to be able to fill it inn? @KunLun

Comment: @Magnus2142 no. A variable is visible anywhere in the block(`{ }`) where is declared. In your case, `letterArray` is visible in class `Tekst...{ ... }` . Here is an code example: https://onlinegdb.com/r1zljS88H of variable scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`charAt` returns a `char`, which is the [UTF-16 code unit](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) in the Java string at the position you requested. For instance, `'A'` is the `char` whose `int` value is `65` (`'B'` is `66` and so on); `'a'` is the `char` whose `int` value is `97` (`'b'` is `98` and so on); etc. You can convert a `char` to an `int` by simply assigning it to an `int` variable or using it in any `int` context (such as indexing into an array or as part of a subtraction expression) or via an explicit cast:

```
int codeUnit = this.text.charAt(i);
```

Then you need to do some math on the result to determine the correct index for your array, and increment the value there.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TekstVerktøy{
    private int[] letterArray =null;

    public TekstVerktøy(String t){
        letterArray =  new int[t.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
            letterArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(t.charAt(i)+"");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TekstVerktøy tekstVerktøy = new TekstVerktøy("123123213123123123213213213");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tekstVerktøy.letterArray));
    }
}
```

If you place alphabet in the constructor it will give number format exception, you need to handle that.